# ASP.NET button server click event not firing after jquery e.preventdefault() fires

Tags: c#, jquery

I have a web page where I use jQuery AJAX to load data from a database to fill a drop down list. When the jQuery function runs, the server events does not fire.

jQuery:

```
 $('#Cmb_PDept').on('change', function (e) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    var DepartmentId = $('#Cmb_PDept :selected').val();
                    if (DepartmentId == 0) {
                        EmpCombo.empty();
                        textbox.val("");

                        return;
                    }
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        cache: false,
                        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                        url: '/WebService/GetEmployeeByDepID.asmx/GetEmployee',
                        data: '{ "DepartmentId": "' + DepartmentId + '" }',
                        dataType: 'json',
                        success: function (data) {
                            var data = $.parseJSON(data.d)
                            var options = $("#Cmb_PEmp");
                            options.empty();
                            for (var i = 0; i < data.length ; i++) {
                                options.append("<option value='" + data[i]["EmployeeId"] + "'>" + data[i]["EmployeeName"] + "</option>");   
                            }
                            myEvent();
                        },
                        error: function () { alert("error"); }
                    });
                });
```

ASP.NET `Button` control

```
<asp:Button ID="Btn_PIncrementSave" runat="server" Text="Save" 
            OnClick="Btn_PIncrementSave_Click" CausesValidation="false" />
```

The `onClick` event

```
protected void Btn_PIncrementSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        try
        {
            TxBx_IncrementAmount.Text = Hid_BasicSalary.Value;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Utility.Msg_Error(this.Master, ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

This event does not fire. I think this is due to

```
 e.preventDefault();
```

When I remove this, the server-side event works properly.

Comment: If you want it to fire why are you even using e.preventdefault?

Comment: `e.preventDefault();` if removing this working well then what is the issue?

Comment: when jquery executs its fuction server side events not fire.i bypass all jquery events then button click fire.when ever i executes jquery events server envents not fire.

Comment: you remove the e.PreventDefault() and add ClientIDMode="Static" in dropdown attributes, then try

Comment: when i remove e.preventDefult() jquery events not fire

Comment: is your ajax call working fine, check it in firebug its returning data or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To your ASP button add this `ClientIDMode="Static"` and Check. Weather the `ASP:Button` **ID** will be changed when the source is moved to Browser. May be that will be one reason. Check the `ID` by clicking the view source in your Browser.

Comment: try the way @RJK is saying, this will also resolve your issue actually when page is rendered asp.net changes the ids on client side so thats the issue

Comment: i alredy include cleintMode-sataic in web.confiq file

Comment: @AmjadShah Please [Read this](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/event_preventdefault.asp)

Answer (score 2):

your answer is in the title of question, if you use `e.PreventDefault()` it stops to fire the server side event or if you write `return false` statement in that case also server side event will not fire. You remove the `e.PreventDefault()` form your code, it will fire then.